# Добавление обработчика события кнопке, созданной в функции

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как обратиться к кнопке, которая была создана в функции?

```
$(function() {
    $('#create').click(function(){
        document.getElementById('select').innerHTML = '<button id="choice"></button>'
    });
});

$(function() {
    $('#choice').click(function() {
        ...
    });
});
```

Comment: через делегирование: $('#select').on('#choice', 'click', function(){}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    $('#create').click(function() {
        document.getElementById('select').innerHTML = '<button id="choice"></button>'
    });
});

$(function() {
    $('body').on('click', '#choice', function() {
    ....
});
```

P.S. Хотя странно, что при использовании jQuery вы используете `document.getElementById`

Comment: Пока что просто разбираюсь, согласен, что глупо.  Спасибо за ответ)